# Caluculating torque as a vector product

Tags: forces, vectors, torque, textbook-erratum

Can someone please explain to me why the vector used for Force in calculating torque is F=3.0j when the problem explicitly states that the magnitude is 3.9N?
[image]

Comment: Obviously a typographical error. They may have simply seen the number 3.0 (the mass) and were not careful in their proofreading. It should be 3.9.

Comment: Wow, I always thought the textbook answer key is absolute. I've been told that the author of this textbook (Paul A. Tipler) is supposedly a physics prodigy.

Comment: Maybe a physics prodigy, but I seriously doubt that he created the answer key. Probably a grad student many years ago and the publisher never corrected the error.  Publishers are really lazy about correcting mistakes.  Most answer keys have at least 1 error. Congratulations on finding that one.

Comment: LOL, yeah I was checking my answer and was wondering why it was so way off, then I checked their method and found this nonsense. I thought something was wrong with me, but it was them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further speculation and other's opinions, we have concluded that this may have just been a typo. If anyone somehow finds an explanation to support the answer key's calculation, then please feel free to post your answer.